# I need to give link from variable to execute_script(new window) in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, execute-script

I have a code that will open a new window and switched to before and after which like in code. But I what to give the link from variable why because if I have multiple links to search. For eg:`search_url =["https://www.google.com", "https://www.yahoo.com", "https://www.bing.com"]` Here is my code:

```
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com")
window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
window_before_title = driver.title
print(window_before_title)

#open a new window
driver.execute_script("window.open('http://www.twitter.com', 'new window')")
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]

#switch on to new child window
driver.switch_to.window(window_after)
time.sleep(10)

window_after_title = driver.title
print(window_after_title)

#Compare and verify that main window and child window title don't match
if window_before_title != window_after_title:
    print('Context switched to Twitter, so the title did not match')
else:
    print('Control did not switch to new window')

#switch back to original window
driver.switch_to.window(window_before)

#Verify that the title now match
if window_before_title == driver.title:
    print('Context returned to parent window. Title now match')
    print(driver.title)
```

From here`driver.execute_script("window.open('http://www.twitter.com', 'new window')")` I want to use `search_url`instead of`'http://www.twitter.com'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then if i understood correctly what you wrote instead of `driver.execute_script("window.open('http://www.twitter.com', 'new window')")` you have to  write `driver.execute_script("window.open('" + search_url[i] + "', 'new window')")` in a for loop.

Comment: I tried your code (https://drive.google.com/file/d/19-44o1us73Y7kwpifjRW1FhpYpNH0-pt/view?usp=sharing) its through the quotation error. I tried all possible ways please help me to find a solution.

Comment: Sorry, i missed the '+' symbols. I've edited my answer.